# sharepoint masterpage security trimmed control for groups

Tags: sharepoint

For a **SharePoint 2013 Foundation**, how to do security trim on user groups? I know there is a tag for trimming content based on the permission mask, namely:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ...>
```

but how do I achieve the same thing for custom groups? You could, for example, put every user into the according group based on the location he is working at. (e.g. New York, Seattle, etc.) Based on the group, you display another set of assets like .css, .js, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The security trim tag won't allow you to use a specific group as a value for the PermissionString property. Here is a list of possible acceptable values of permission levels:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms412690